# best way to split a base64 encoded pdf in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have a string containing a 2 page base64 encoded PDF file.  The second page of the PDF is always garbage.  (Terms and conditions from the web service that sent me the PDF.)  I would like to be able to modify the PDF to drop the second junk page and re-encode it as base64 data, ideally without writing to the disk.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It being base64-encoded doesn't change your approach.  You must decode it before doing the work, and then re-encode it.  I suggest splitting your question into two pieces to get better answers, if this hasn't been answered already.

Answer (score 0):

Well 24 hours later and a lot of research and I have come up with the answer.  Brad is correct, this should have probably been split into two questions, although decoding the base64 data is very simple and has been covered multiple times on this site so I will not go into detail on how to do that.  The real kicker for me was finding a framework that would let you load the PDF from a string, not from the disk.  The answer is the zend framework.

```
// Load the PDF
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::parse($pdfString);
// Remove the page from the pages array
unset($pdf->pages[$id]);
// Return the PDF document as a string
$pdfString = $pdf->render();
```